# Magnolia CMS- Charge dialog of SelectFieldDefinition

Tags: java, magnolia

I need to change the fields of the SelectFieldDefinition from a BBDD, i have to connect to bbdd in the java method, but i can't find the java method which change the fields 
[image: fields]

I´ve searched in class `SelectFieldDefinition` which extends ConfiguredFieldDefinition but i don´t find anything

Any Help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that by BBDD you mean database and by charging you mean loading...

```
public class DomainSelectFieldFactory extends SelectFieldFactory {
@Override
public List<SelectFieldOptionDefinition> getSelectFieldOptionDefinition() {
    List<SelectFieldOptionDefinition> options = new ArrayList<SelectFieldOptionDefinition>();
    List<Domain> allDomains = getAllDomains(); 
    for (Domain domain : allDomains) {
        SelectFieldOptionDefinition option = new SelectFieldOptionDefinition();
        option.setValue(domain.id);
        option.setLabel(domain.name);
        options.add(option);
     }
    return options;
} ...



public class DomainSelectFieldDefinition extends SelectFieldDefinition {

public DomainSelectFieldDefinition() {
    setTransformerClass((Class<? extends Transformer<?>>) (Object) BasicTransformer.class);
}
```

Then in your module configuration under "fieldTypes" you define your field type with "definitionClass" and "factoryClass"
[image]

Comment: Thanks bro!!  The tutorial here: https://wiki.magnolia-cms.com/pages/viewpage.action?spaceKey=TRAINING53&title=Exercise%3A+Create+Form+Field+Factory